# ROS2 Foxy : DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API

Tags: ros2, python3, ros-foxy

I am trying to fly a tello drone in a gazebo simulation [ROS Driver for the tello Drone](https://github.com/clydemcqueen/tello_ros). When I try running the following script, (after ofcourse building the package) -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

class DroneSim(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('velocity_publisher_node')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Twist, '/drone1/cmd_vel', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        twist = Twist()
        twist.linear.x = 1.0
        twist.angular.z = 1.0
        # add code to check if drone has taken off and only then publish velocity
        self.publisher_.publish(twist)
        self.get_logger().info(f'Publishing: {twist.linear.x}, {twist.angular.z}')
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    drone_sim = DroneSim()

    rclpy.spin(drone_sim)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    drone_sim.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I use the following command to run the script -

```
ros2 run drone_sim test.py
```

I face the following error -

```
/opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
No executable found
```

I have tried upgrading, uninstalling and installing setuptools package, and numerous other things but it still does not seem to work.

I am on Ubunutu 20.04 and running ROS2 Foxy. The package is an ament_cmake package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade setuptools when you are using ROS2 foxy. Which is [a known issue (mentioned here in the ROS 2 repository)](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/issues/382) :)

`pip3 install setuptools==58.2.0`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I was able to get this running successfully. I honestly don't remember how as I didn't document it at the time. 
Thabk you so much for the help. Hopefully this is helpful to someone.